# Shouldn't there be "which is" before the "ready" here?

Tags: grammar

It was only next morning, when it grew light, that they noticed their visitor, who stood trembling before them, **with his eye on the door ready to escape at any moment.** They did not, however, appear very fierce, and the duckling became less afraid as they approached him.
It is the ugly  ducking story.

Comment: That would mean that the door was ready to escape, not the visitor! (It would have to be _which was_ , as the passage is in the past tense.)

Comment: @KateBunting - also, without a comma after 'door', doesn't it mean his eye was ready to escape?

Answer (score 1):

The omitted word is ***being***. You can understand that part of the sentence in this way:

> *[Their visitor]* stood trembling before them, with his eye on the door ***[(and) being]*** ready to escape at any moment.

*Ready* describes the attitude of the subject *their visitor* (which was replaced in the relative sentence by ***who***): He stood being ready to escape.

Answer (score -1):

The structures used in the English language are not necessairy those that are used in other languages. I'm translating that sentence into Persian and then will translate the Persian sentence into English word by word. This will most likely work with most other languages. Then you will understand what it really means:

*They noticed their visitor, who stood trembling before them, while his eye was on the door and was ready to escape at any moment.*